# How to implement REST webservices with basic authentication?

Tags: web-services, rest

in REST we will talk about everything is represents as a resource. (Uniform URI).

so in this case, If I want to pass sensitive data (ex: credit card number) via browser, I need to apply authentication after that I have to send request.

So how to send REST request through URL with authenticated data?

If you need any more details I will provide you.

Please help me.

Regards,
Sriram.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use HTTPS
2. Use POST to post your sensitive data and encrypt the contents of the POST.
3. Make sure that you authenticate the user(Basic Auth, spnego ..)

Comment: hi Thanks for your reply. How to encrypt the sensitive data before sending to the server? Because in REST no client side coding. If you have any sample can you please provide me.

Comment: There are many options. [This](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx) is how you can do it in C#